# Driver MongoDB with xampp-win32-5.6.12-0-VC11 "The specified module could not be found"

Tags: php, windows, mongodb, xampp, driver

I was trying to connect mongodb to php of xampp with version **"xampp-win32-5.6.12-0-VC11-installer"**, but always error.
I use driver from **"https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/php_mongo-1.6.8.zip"**

The message log is :
**"[22-Sep-2015 13:13:11 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\XAMPP\php\ext\php_mongo.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0"**

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Rename "php_mongo-1.6.8-5.6-vc11.dll" to "php_mongo.dll" in ext folder.

Comment: currently I have done it before. And now still error.